# Is the highlighted area grammatically correct? "[...] has recently shown to hold great promises."

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

Is the highlighted area below grammatically correct? If not, how would you modify it?

"Improving conventional imaging techniques especially through combining them with molecular biology methods **has recently shown to hold great promises**."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Promise", in that use, should not be plural.

[American Heritage Dictionary "promise"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=promise)

> 2. Indication of something favorable to come; expectation: *a promise of spring in the air.*
> 3. Indication of future excellence or success: *a player of great promise.*

The expression "has recently shown to hold" is not grammatical.

It would be grammatical to say
"has recently been shown to hold great promise"

But it would be more idiomatic to say simply:
"has recently shown great promise".